# 'Learn more' button for privileges mistakenly links to Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

After earning my first reputation on channels, I was interested in seeing the privileges available. 
I went to my channels profile, and then clicked 'Learn more' after seeing my next privilege:

[image]

This redirected here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

I *should* have actually been redirected here: https://stackoverflow.com/c/sobotics/help/privileges/set-bounties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your report! The issue has been fixed and will be live with our next prod build.